# Find sublist with given sum

Tags: list, lisp

Given a list `L=(M,A1,A2,...,An)`. Find sublist if they exist `L1=(Ai,Ai+1,...,Ai+k), i+k<=N, i>=1,` for which  `M=Ai+Ai+1+...Ai+k`

For example 1: `L=(12 1 3 -16 5 7 8 2 2), M=12`
Result: `L=((1 3 -16)(5 7)(8 2 2))`
for `1+3-16=12, 5+7=12, 8+2+2=12`

Exemple `L=(14 1 15 -1 14 5 6)`
Result: `L=((15 -1)(14))`
for `1=14->no`, `1+15=14->no`, `1+15-1=14->no`, `1+15-1+14=14->no`, `1+15-1+14+5=14->no`, `1+15-1+14+5+6=14->no`
we move on to the next item `15=14->no`, `15-1=14->YES!` extract `(15 -1)` 
we move on to the next item `14=14->YES!` extract `(14)`
we move on to the next item `5=14->no`, `5+6=14->no`
Finish Result `(15 -1) (14)`

How resolve it in Lisp?

My code

```
(setq l '(6 1 2 3 6 14 3))
(setq comb nil)
(setq rez nil)
(defun sublist (lst)
    (secondfunction (car lst) (cdr lst)) 
)
(defun pairnil (list1)
  (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (cons x nil)) list1)
)
(defun pair (a list1)
  (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (append  x  (list a))) list1)
)
(defun secondfunction (head other)
    (run (cdr other) (cdr other) (pairnil other) (cdr(pairnil other)) (pairnil(car(pairnil other))))
    (final comb head nil)
)
(defun final (lst el result)
(if (>(length lst) 0)
    (progn
        (if(eq(loop for x in (car lst) sum x) el) (final (cdr lst) el (append result (cons (car lst) nil)))
        (if(>(length lst) 0)(final (cdr lst) el result )))
    ) 
    (setq rez result)   
))
(final comb (car l) nil)
(defun run (lst1 ilst1 lst2 ilst2 temp)
    (if (eq(car ilst1) nil) (setq comb lst2))
    (when (>(length lst1)0)
        (if (>(length ilst1)0) (run lst1 (cdr ilst1) (append lst2 (pair (car ilst1) temp)) ilst2 (append temp (pair (car ilst1) temp))))
        (if (=(length ilst1)0) (run (cdr lst1) (cdr lst1) lst2 (cdr ilst2) (pairnil(car ilst2))))       
    ))
(sublist l)
```

Result `((6) (1 2 3) (1 2 3) (3 3))`, but this doesn't work correctly. In example I have explained how it should work.

Comment: It is kind of difficult to guess what your functions do, given the strange names for the functions (run, final), the strange names for the variables (ilst1, comb, lst2, rez, ...), the lack of comments and the less than optimal formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach:

```
map over all sublists of list and append the results
    map over all sublists of this reversed sublist and append the results
      when the sum of the items is M then collect a list of the reverse sublist
```

Functions needed:

- `mapcon` for mapping
- `reverse` for reversing
- `reduce` for summing

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
(setq l '(6 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 -1))
(setq comb nil)
(setq rez nil)

(defun sublist (lst)
(secondfunction (car lst) (cdr lst)) 
)

(defun secondfunction (head other)
(run (cdr other) (cdr other) (list(car other)) (list(list(car other))))
(final comb head nil)
)

(defun final (lst el result)

(if (>(length lst) 0)
(progn
    (if(eq(loop for x in (car lst) sum x) el) (final (cdr lst) el (append result (cons (car lst) nil)))
    (if(>(length lst) 0)(final (cdr lst) el result )))
) 
(setq rez result)   
)

)

(final comb (car l) nil)

(defun run (lst1  lst2 temp r)

(if (not(eq(car lst1) nil))
    (if (not(eq(car lst2) nil))
        (run lst1 (cdr lst2) (append temp (list (car lst2))) (append r (list (append temp (list (car lst2))))))
        (run (cdr lst1) (cdr lst1) (list(car lst1)) (append r (list(list (car lst1)))))
    )
    (setq comb r)
)




)


(sublist l)
```